# How to instantiate Particle System at the same place where we click a gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate the particle system when clicking the coins in my game but the Particle System is not appearing at the same place where my coins are.

I used this code, I don't know where to specify the position of a Particle System in the same place where I am clicking (mouse position) or where the coins are. I used prefab for my coins and tagged them. and also pickupeffect clone is created when I click the coin so I need to destroy them  after few seconds

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint 
        (Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
    }
    if (hit.collider != null) {
       if (hit.collider.tag == "coin") {
           Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Pickupeffect"));
           Destroy (hit.collider.gameObject);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `hit.collider.gameObject` position and instantiate your system in the same position after you destroy the coin. Have in mind that if the coin inherits a position different than `x=0, y=0` you may want to instantiate the object and set the same parent. The code should like this:

```
if (hit.collider.tag == "coin") {
    ReplaceCoinWithSys(hit.collider.gameObject, Resources.Load ("Pickupeffect"))
}
```

and the method should be like this:

```
private void ReplaceCoinWithSys(GameObject coin, GameObject system){   
    Instantiate(system,new Vector2 (coin.transform.position.x, coin.transform.position.y), Quaternion.identity);
    Destroy (coin);
}
```

I hope this helps, hit me up when you complete your game I want to try it out :)

Comment: Few things: 1) it's better to cache an integer layer and compare collider.layer with the one you cached, rather than compare strings; 2) it's better to cache your partical system and reuse it rather than loading resource each time you call that method; 3) Calling an instantiate and destroy each time is a super bad practice.. You want to instantiate objects only when you don't have enough. In this case i'd rather reuse pre existent instances of particle systems and coins. Coins can be reusable also. You don't want to call instantiate and destroy when it's possible to avoid it. It's expensive.

Comment: @earthQuake Hi :) When it comes to the tag and string I just copied the author's condition and paste it xaxa. Now about reusing what do you mean by that. Let's say we have, 'k - t' coins where 't' is the count of coins picked at that moment of time and the systems count is r + t where 'r' is the starting count of the systems (I assume it's 0) then when I pick a coin 't' is increasing (the count of the picked coins) and so the picture have to change by destroying on of the existing coins and creating a new system. How can I optimize this (I am not professional game dev sorry)

Comment: I was talking about that you don't have to instantiate all the coins for your level at once. You just instantiate those that you actually see on the screen and put it back to objects pool when it's picked up or out of screen. And when you have to show more coins than you have in a pool, then you instantiate it, but then recycle it instead of destroying. The same to Particle Systems and whatever other objects..

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help you

```
    private Gameobject ObjectThatYouNeedToDestroy;// gameobject initialization

   void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
    }
    if (hit.collider != null)
```

So, when the clicked object is a coin, then :

```
    if (hit.collider.tag == "coin") {
```

Instantiate the object at the position of object that is being hit by cursor (`hit.transform.position`) with default prefab rotation (`Quaternion.identity`).

```
        Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Pickupeffect"), hit.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);//instantiate particle prefab in coin position with original prefab rotation
        float DelayTime = 5f;// change delay with any value
```

Assign the hit object to variable `ObjectThatYouNeedToDestroy`, in case that the value `hit.transform.gameobject` can't be assessed in another function.

```
        ObjectThatYouNeedToDestroy= hit.transform.gameobject;// assign coin that clicked as ObjectThatYouNeedToDestroy
```

The last step is to execute `DelayedDestroy` function after delay time expires.

```
        Invoke ("DelayedDestroy", DelayTime);//execute function with delay
    }
}
```

this is the function that destroy gameobject named `ObjectThatYouNeedToDestroy` (coin)

```
void DelayedDestroy(){
    Destroy (ObjectThatYouNeedToDestroy);
}
```